# Configure s3 event for alternate PUT operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, put

I have a Lambda function that gets triggered whenever an object is created in s3 bucket.

Now, I need to trigger the Lambda for alternate object creation.
Lambda should not be triggered when object is created for the first, third , fifth and so on time. But, Lambda should be triggered for the second, fourth, sixth and so on time.

For this, I created an s3 event for 'PUT' operation.
The first time I used the PUT API. The second time I uploaded the file using -

> s3_res.meta.client.upload_file

I thought that it would not trigger lambda since this was upload and not PUT. But this also triggered the Lambda.

Is there any way for this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `meta.client.upload_file` is triggering your `PUT` event lambda is because it *is* actually using `PUT`.

`upload_file` ([docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file)) uses the TransferManager client, which uses `PUT` under-the-hood (you can see this in the code: https://github.com/boto/s3transfer/blob/develop/s3transfer/upload.py)

Looking at the AWS-SDK you'll see that `POST`'ing to S3 is pretty much limited to when you want to give a browser/client a pre-signed URL for them to upload a file to. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html)

If you want to count the number of times `PUT` has been called, in order to take action on every even call, then the easiest thing to do is to use something like DynamoDB to create a table of 'file-name' vs 'put-count' which you update with every `PUT` and action accordingly.

Alternatively you could enable bucket file versioning. Then you could use [`list_object_versions`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_object_versions) to see how many times the file has been updated. Although you should be aware that S3 is eventually consistent, so this may not be accurate if the file is being rapidly updated.